# How to display text based on condition

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
If Request("cid") = 15 'Hudson Health Plan
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "<A href='http://myintra1/checkfile.aspx?id=90' target='_blank'>Click here for participating providers and the provider participating location/s.  </a> <br/>" & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
End If
If Request("cid") = 57 Then 'Hudson Health Plan
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "<A href='http://myintra1/checkfile.aspx?id=23' target='_blank'>Click here for participating providers and the provider participating location/s.  </a> <br/>" & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
End If

The above code shows correctly...
```

[image]

```
If Request("cid") = 15 And e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Y" Then   'Hudson Health Plan
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "<A href='http://myintra1/checkfile.aspx?id=90' target='_blank'>Click here for participating providers and the provider participating location/s.  </a> <br/>" & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
Else
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = ""
End If
If Request("cid") = 57 And e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Y" Then   'Health Plus Amerigroup/Empire BCBS
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "<A href='http://myintra1/checkfile.aspx?id=23' target='_blank'>Click here for participating providers and the provider participating location/s.  </a> <br/>" & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
Else
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = ""
End If

The above code shows correctly but it does not concatenate the text like it did in the first section of code....
```

[image]

How can I resolve the issue, if the `CID` matches and the third column is a "Y", then display the link plus the text. If the "CID" matches and the third column is a "N", then display nothing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the second picture is for `cid = 57`, what happens is first `else` is executed, cell gets empty value, and then second `then` is executed, and link is concatenated to an empty, previously cleared, value. To fix all this, just use `elseif`:

```
If Request("cid") = 15 And e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Y" Then   'Hudson Health Plan
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "<A href='http://myintra1/checkfile.aspx?id=90' target='_blank'>Click here for participating providers and the provider participating location/s.  </a> <br/>" & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
Elseif Request("cid") = 57 And e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Y" Then   'Health Plus Amerigroup/Empire BCBS
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "<A href='http://myintra1/checkfile.aspx?id=23' target='_blank'>Click here for participating providers and the provider participating location/s.  </a> <br/>" & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
Else
    e.Row.Cells(11).Text = ""
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to append the cell with the link if the condition of "Y" is met in e.Row.Cells(3).Text

Case statements would probably be your best bet and they are easier to read since you do not have complex if elseif conditions.

```
If e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Y" Then 

    Select case Request("cid")

        case 15
            e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "CID = 15 link " & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
        case 57
            e.Row.Cells(11).Text = "CID = 57 link " & e.Row.Cells(11).Text
        case else
            e.Row.Cells(11).Text = ""
    End Select

End If
```